# Add Enviroment variable on script tag in react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have a requirement to pass the environment variable in index.html in react app in the script tag.

```
<script src='static content {dynamic content from enviroment variable}'></script>
```

Comment: Is that required during development or when you are building for production?

Comment: Why don't you import the JS file in your source?